# SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: Joomla 3.0 and 2.5

Tags: webforms, smtp, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, contact-form-7

everyone !! I detect in my work that Contact Form in Joomla have a problems. In old time, never have the problems.
But in the moment, I try send email from Contact Form, and have a problems.

In Global Configurations i used  PHP email , with one xxxx@gmail.com in different websites and never have a problem.

The Problem :
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host productio-tcloadba-tkyjfaz4ap1l-328615543.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com [54.214.48.123]:
    550 5.7.1 [BFD] Sender prohibited by SPF

How fix this problem !!  and the emails go back in normal mailbox !!
Someone people have one good idea for fix the problems in Contact Forms in Jommla

Thanks a lot in advanced !!